# Filter out non 200 status codes axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, httpclient

When doing requests at the same time, if there's a non 200 code, it will get caught in the catch block instead of I want to filter them out. Seems to work with node fetch but not axios, is there any other way to do this?

```js
try {
    const requests = urls.map((url) => axios.get(url));
    const responses = await axios.all(requests);

    const failedResponses = responses.filter(
      (response) => response.status !== 200
    );

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
```

Instead of it throwing on a single error in the catch block, I want to filter out the errors.

Comment: Can you use `Promise.allSettled` instead?

Answer (score -1):

You can filter out failed responses in an Axios parallel request scenario by utilizing Promise.allSettled. Here's how you can adjust your code to implement this ~

```js
const requests = urls.map((url) => axios.get(url));
const responses = await Promise.allSettled(requests);

const successfulResponses = responses
  .filter(({
    status
  }) => status === 'fulfilled')
  .map(({
    value
  }) => value);

const failedResponses = responses
  .filter(({
    status
  }) => status === 'rejected')
  .map(({
    reason
  }) => reason);

// Handle successfulResponses and failedResponses as needed
```

The code then allows you to handle successfulResponses and failedResponses separately based on your application's needs. This condensed code maintains the same functionality as the original code but presents it in a more concise and readable form.